# Extending the axis bar height in d3 js charts

Tags: css, d3.js

I have created a bar chart using d3. Now I want extend the height of the x axis but couldn't find out how to do so. The height attr doesnt work and stroke attr just updates the tick text. Is there any way to extend height without changing the text labels.

Here is the link of what I am trying to do : [Adding background color in d3 js bar chart using data values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46279803/adding-background-color-in-d3-js-bar-chart-using-data-values)

Comment: What you mean by *"the height of the axis"*?

Comment: Height here refers to the  height of the orange box in which we have text labels.

Comment: I trying to create another rect element and put it onto the bottom with specified height and width

Comment: Here i can create rect box but is there any other way to do it using d3 axis functions?svg.append("rect").attr("x","0").attr("y","450").attr("width","920").attr("height","50").attr("fill","orange").attr("fill-opacity","0.3").classed("axis-label",true);

Comment: No, there is no native way. Unless you change the stroke-width of the axis path, but that will give you an extremely ugly result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46279803/5768908), just add a rectangle before appending the axis:

```
var orangeBox = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", height)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", margin.bottom)
    .attr("fill", "orange")
    .attr("opacity", 0.2);
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var mydata = {
  "min": 68.9813,
  "avg": 177.5037,
  "max": 672.6713,
  "values": [{
    "bin": -50.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 0.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 50.0,
    "percent": 6.7028,
    "samples": 309
  }, {
    "bin": 100.0,
    "percent": 32.2897,
    "samples": 2407
  }, {
    "bin": 150.0,
    "percent": 32.4565,
    "samples": 3207
  }, {
    "bin": 200.0,
    "percent": 17.1745,
    "samples": 2064
  }, {
    "bin": 250.0,
    "percent": 6.1833,
    "samples": 940
  }, {
    "bin": 300.0,
    "percent": 2.4971,
    "samples": 444
  }, {
    "bin": 350.0,
    "percent": 1.2438,
    "samples": 279
  }, {
    "bin": 400.0,
    "percent": 0.9262,
    "samples": 182
  }, {
    "bin": 450.0,
    "percent": 0.2781,
    "samples": 71
  }, {
    "bin": 500.0,
    "percent": 0.0962,
    "samples": 24
  }, {
    "bin": 550.0,
    "percent": 0.074,
    "samples": 25
  }, {
    "bin": 600.0,
    "percent": 0.0535,
    "samples": 24
  }, {
    "bin": 650.0,
    "percent": 0.0243,
    "samples": 6
  }, {
    "bin": 700.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 750.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 800.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 850.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 900.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 950.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }, {
    "bin": 1000.0,
    "percent": 0.0,
    "samples": 0
  }],
  "index": 7,
  "time_h": 13.8529,
  "stddev": 67.8836,
  "samples": 9982
};


//set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);


function make_x_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(2)
}

// gridlines in y axis function
function make_y_gridlines() {
  return d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(10)
}
// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .style('fill', 'black');;

// get the data
// d3.csv("sales.csv", function(error, data) {
//   if (error) throw error;

//   // format the data
//   data.forEach(function(d) {
//     d.sales = +d.sales;
//   });

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(mydata.values.map(function(d) {
  return d.bin;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(mydata.values, function(d) {
  return d.percent;
})]);

var redBox = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", x(200) + x.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", x(x.domain()[x.domain().length - 1]) - x(200) + x.bandwidth() / 2)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("opacity", 0.2);
  
var orangeBox = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", height)
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", margin.bottom)
  .attr("fill", "orange")
  .attr("opacity", 0.2);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(mydata.values)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.bin) + (x.bandwidth() - 4) / 2;
  })
  .attr("width", Math.min(x.bandwidth(), 5))
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.percent);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.percent);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(make_x_gridlines()
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickFormat("")
  );

// add the Y gridlines
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_gridlines()
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickFormat("")
  );


// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```